# Xml element valid if space in the name?

Tags: xml

Im looking over some xml files and see some of them are different only in the element names.
Are both of these valid xml element names?

```
<MyOption />   <MyOption/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a space in the name (`<My Option/>`), but that isn't what you have there.

You have spaces between the end of the name and the end of the tag, which is perfectly acceptable.

The `/` character is not part of the name. It is the [empty-element tag syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-starttags) that causes the tag to represent the whole element (so there are no child nodes and no separate end tag).